# Setting different values to td for asp:Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've recently started working with `<asp:Repeater/>`. I have a table in the database with the following columns

1. `ID`
2. `Message`
3. `Flag`

I'm not allowed to alter the table in any way. The messages that are stored are from managers and employees. Only way to find out which message belongs to who is by the `Flag` column which has `manager` or `employee` flag. Now I need to read from this table and display it on a webform developed in asp.net. I can read the values no problem but the issue is that I need to display it as a convo one after another so i've used a `<asp:Repeater/>` but I can't seem to put the messages in different `td` for example

First row should have manager messages

Second row should have employee messages

The code below is my effort so far.

**Markup**

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<tr>
    <td class="manager">
         <%:GetMessage("manager") %>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="employee">
        <%:GetMessage("employee") %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the C# code

```
protected string GetMessage(string flagIndicator)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        string myQuery = @"SELECT MESSAGES FROM MYTABLE WHERE FLAG = @flag";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", flagIndicator);
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Message = reader["MESSAGES"].ToString();
                    MyRepeater.DataSource = reader;
                    MyRepeater.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //How to return the messages so they are spilt up by the flag
}

private string Message { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you want to display all messages with certain flag in one td? At least your markup does that. What is repeater for then?

Comment: @Andrei Yes that's what I want to do. But it will only work if I put my code in `Page_Load`. If I call my `GetMessage()` nothing is displayed on the page

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="pageList" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
      <td class='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Flag"]%>'>
        <%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Message"]%>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pageList.DataSource = GetAllMessages();
   pageList.DataBind();   
}
```

Business:

```
    protected DataTable GetAllMessages()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
        {
            string myQuery = @"SELECT MESSAGES FROM MYTABLE";

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

            DataSet messagesDS = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(messagesDS, "MYTABLE");

            return messagesDS.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't display the message one after another and also doesn't distinguish between empoyee and manager message

Comment: I get an error `SqlCommand` does not have a definition of `ExecuteDataSet`... what namespace is `ExecuteDataSet` in? Ps - how is your code distinguishing between manager and employee messages?

Comment: This code displays all messages in the order they are in the database, and for each message applies the specific CSS class ("manager" or "employee"). If you need to split the 2 Flags, than you need 2 repeaters (one for manager messages and one for employee messages), but the concept is the same, you need to bind the repeater to a collection (ex: DataTable)

Comment: Surely there must be an easier way to achieve this rather than me writing the same code for each reapter

Comment: You can make repeater inside repeater.